# Getting Access token

Tags: c#, authentication, access-token, claims-based-identity, auth-token

I have `claims/Auth_token` information, which looks like

```
{
    "claims": null,
    "auth_token": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP==",
    "refresh_token": null,
    "auth_token_expiration": "2012-09-04T06:59:13.1343331-04:00",
    "refresh_token_expiration": "2013-05-01T06:59:13.1343331-04:00",
    "token_type": "urn:Test1:Test2:grant-type:trusted_issuer"
}
url=www.testuri.com
```

Using this I need to create a utility which fetches the access token of the uri using the claims information mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

The information you are getting is `JSON`

You can deserialize JSON into objects with the JavaScriptSerializer class in C#.

First you'll have to build a POCO object which represents the structure of your json:

```
public class ResponseObj
{
    public string claims { get; set; }
    public string auth_token { get; set; }
    public string refresh_token { get; set; }
    public DateTime auth_token_expiration { get; set; }
    public DateTime refresh_token_expiration { get; set; }
    public string token_type { get; set; }
}
```

After that you can deserialize it like this and use the result to fetch the token:

```
string json = "your json string"
ResponseObj deserializedResult = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ResponseObj>(json);

string token = deserializedResult.auth_token;
```

Note that now you can access all properties in the response just like the auth token.
If you'll want to get the claims string you could use;

```
string claims = deserializedResult.claims;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a JSON string

You need to create a class with properties (claims,auth_token,refresh_token...etc)

Then DeSerialize this JSON string and then you can access the token.

```
    public class TokenResponse
    {
     public string claims { get; set; }
     public string auth_token { get; set; }
     public string refresh_token { get; set; }
     public string auth_token_expiration { get; set; }
     public string refresh_token_expiration { get; set; }
     public string token_type { get; set; }
    }
```

Now deserialize JSON:

```
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var token = js.Deserialize<TokenResponse>(decodedResponse);
```

Now use the token:

```
    string authToken=token.auth_token
```